# Identifying specific devices when using sensors in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, lm-sensors

I am running the `sensors` command in Ubuntu 20.04 to try and get a temperature reading for my NVME SSD drives. However, although I can see the drives I am not sure which one is which:

```
nvme-pci-2300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +45.9°C  (low  =  -5.2°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)

nvme-pci-6100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +52.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +86.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +52.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +51.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 3:     +52.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-2e00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +51.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +51.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +57.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

The only obvious difference between each of these is the number that comes after `nvme-pci-` but these don't seem to correspond to my model numbers and Googling them just results in a whole load of different models and brands.

I tried running `lspci` and `lsblk` in the hope that there would be something else to help me to link these numbers to the devices but there is not.

In short, I just want to know with absolute certainty the temperature of each NVME SSD device in my system.

Comment: @anx Yes, you are absolutely right. I was way too focused on trying to get the info from the sensors command! If you'd like to post this as an answer then I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders in the respective `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/` contain a `device/` symlink that points to the device the sensor is registered with. After enumerating the sensors you can retrieve vendor, path or serial from that subfolder (e.g. start with `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/device/modalias`).

Instead of working around the output format of `sensors` or reading *sysfs* yourself, you probably want to **use SMART interface**, which is much more specifically designed to deal with drives, e.g.

```
smartctl -a /dev/disk/by-id/vendor_serial
```

Each invocation of `smartctl` will give you one set of status & temperatures, and you probably already have integration for *SMART* in your monitoring toolbox anyway.